# Dialog does not show in If statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, alert

I have an alert which shows when my form has been saved.

However when I add a dialog it does not work for some reason..

I am using Html.BeginForm and calling onsubmit = "validateForm(event)" as seen below:

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "ReadingsEntry", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", onsubmit = "validateForm(event)" }))
        {
```

I have used this alert which works fine when I click submit:

```
    if (validateForm = true) {
        alert("test");
    }
```

But if I change this to a dialog it does not work:

```
    if (validateForm = true) {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Ok: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

with the html:

```
 <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
<p>Thank you for submitting this form. This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
```

Any idea why my alert works but not my Dialog, am assuming its because maybe its not liking it because its in a if statement?

I have also tried it on the validateForm function:

```
   function validateForm() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Still no luck..

Thanks

Comment: What is validateForm field? And if you are trying to test if it's true you must use == or === operator (inestead of =)... + your function validateForm() does not accept arguments but you are calling this function with arguments: onsubmit = "validateForm(event)"

Comment: what script and css you have used in it . have you used jquery ui css and js ?

Comment: You need to show all your code as the examples above make no sense in isolation. Even that part you say works is wrong.

Comment: Please show the original code of function `validateForm`.

Comment: Did you try to use autoOpen or open(). Even though autoOpen is true by default, please try with open() method of dialog http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-autoOpen ?

Comment: Okay I give up now... that is *part* of the *source code*, not the *output page HTML* requested (twice). The idea is to allow for a non-MVC mockup to be built (e.g. in a JSFiddle) and avoid having to mentally compile your source code. I can't even tell where/if the scripts are included correctly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an assignment of `true` to `validateForm`:

```
if (validateForm = true)
```

So the expression will always be `true` regardless of what was in `validateForm` (and it "was" a function)!

this is a test of the result of calling `validateForm` being equal to `true`:

```
if (validateForm() == true)
```

And this is the preferred way to check a boolean for truthyness:

```
if (validateForm())
```

Having said all that, your `validateForm` does not even return a value, so this entire problem needs a rethink. *Can you please explain the overall aim of your code?* :)

Ignoring the additional issues, you can test further by adding a `return true;` to your function (just for now):

```
function validateForm() {
    ...
    return true
}
```

then this, at least, will now open the dialog:

```
if (validateForm()) {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: sorry its when i click submit button i get a dialog to say success, it works with an alert but doesnt work with .dialog for some reason

Comment: Actually your `alert` will *always* fire as that code is incorrect too.

Comment: its still not working with this:  if (validateForm() == true)

Comment: See my last comment in answer... the whole thing is wrong, hence needing to know what you want to happen :)

Comment: `if (validateForm() == true)` will not fire as  `validateForm()` does not return a value

Comment: all i want is a dialog to open when i click submit. but i dont understand why it doesnt open when i am calling the right stuff

Comment: hi iv added my full javascript code, for some reason when i click the button the dialog shows rather than on save, can you see what am missing please.

Comment: Can you open your project page in a browser and save the entire page HTML/Script to a JSFiddle to share? You new code makes no sense as you validate on page load, then again on submit, but there is no display code in the submit. I would like to help further, but I need to be able to mockup a working example :)

Comment: when i click submit, it runs through the validateForm(). at this point i need to add a statement to show a success message via a dialog box. currently when it says it just reruens back to the last page,

Comment: Your code is ordered incorrectly. The dialog code will never fire as it is only checked once on load. *Please provide the full output HTML/SCRIPT, as saved from your browser*, so that I can suggest a better way of doing this. :)

Comment: full html added. all i want is a dialog box to open once i click submit